# Reflection to Filter List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, asqueryable

I am new to Reflection so please excuse my noob question. How can I create a Method that takes two Parameters, a Generic List and a String and then finds all items in that List where any property value matches the string.

So for example we have an object with 3 properties, I pass a list of this object to the method and a search string and it returns back a list of objects where any of the properties may contain the search string.

I can do like this :

```
var temp = list.AsQueryable().Where("SomeField == 1").Select("it");
```

But how can I make this method Generic so I can pass any List of Objects to it ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is a weird sort of thing to want to do, maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I am building a filter for jTable where I can type in a text and it filters the grid based on the text. jTable uses a List of Objects. I would like to build a generic method so I can use it over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Dynamic Linq, try this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string searchStr)
{
    var propsToCheck = typeof (T).GetProperties().Where(a => a.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    var filter = propsToCheck.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, p) => (s == string.Empty ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0} OR ", s)) + string.Format("{0} == @0", p.Name));

    var filtered = source.AsQueryable().Where(filter, searchStr);
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, how can expand this to allow the .Contains extension ? So instead of 100% match I can just turn up the objects that contain the string ?

Comment: Just change "{0} == @0" to "{0}.Contains(@0)", but you should check for null, so if some properties could be null, use "{0} != null && {0}.Contains(@0)"

Answer (score 2):

Use `Type.GetProperties()` to get all the properties of an object. Use `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` to get the value of a given property in a given object. You need to figure out how you want a match your string to a DateTime, to numbers, or to other complex objects. Put it all into a function like `bool IsMatch(this object obj, string val)`. Then you can filter your list like `list.Where(x => x.IsMatch("something"))`.

Comment: Can you give me an example method ?

Comment: I gave you all the information you need to make it work, but apparently others are more desperate for points :).

Comment: I think the point here is not to brag about theoretical knowledge. Its quite easy to say take a list and filter it. Others are probably here for the spirit of SOF, give an answer, if that wasnt it, why use SOF ? all answers are available at Local Barnes and Noble anyway right ?

Comment: I didn't brag, I didn't give a theoretical answer. I gave you exact details which methods you need to call in order to achieve your goal. You asked for the *how*, I gave you the *how*. You can't expect that the spirit of SO is that people do your work instead of you. Some people do write actual source code sometimes, but that's an extra service.

Comment: I'm with @fejesjoco here. In being given an answer, some may explain how to do it and some may, if possible, provide a complete answer, with working code. You don't get to demand someone do everything for you. They're both answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go mate:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<object> {new {prop1 = "A", prop2 = "B"},new {prop3 = "B", prop4 = "C"}};
        var subList = SearchForStringInProperties(list, "C");
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> SearchForStringInProperties(IEnumerable<object> list, string searchString)
    {
        return from obj in list where FindStringInObjProperties(obj, searchString) select obj;
    }

    private static bool FindStringInObjProperties(object obj, string searchString)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperties().Any(property => obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj).ToString().Equals(searchString));
    }
```

Comment: What if prop1 is null ?

Comment: Good point, and well spotted, yet this is sample code showing a concept, not production ready code.  You could easily check for null also of course.

Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks man, I never thought of doing it this way... Thank you educational

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match the properties with same type as your argument, this extension method can help,

```
 public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MatchWithAnyProperty<T, TK>(this IEnumerable<T> list, TK value)
    {
        var argType = typeof (TK);
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(argType));

      return  list.Where(item => properties.Any(prop =>
            {
                var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                if (value == null)
                    return propertyValue == null;
                return propertyValue.Equals(value);
            }));
    }
}
```

This can be used like,

```
var items = new[]
            {
                new
                    {
                        Name = "Test",
                        Age = 20,
                        Test=25
                    },
                new
                    {
                        Name = "Hello",
                        Age = 10,
                        Test=15
                    },
                new
                    {
                        Name = "T2gdhest",
                        Age = 14,
                        Test=20
                    },
                new
                    {
                        Name = "hai",
                        Age = 33,
                        Test=10
                    },
                new
                    {
                        Name = "why not",
                        Age = 10,
                        Test=33
                    },
            };

       var match= items.MatchWithAnyProperty(10);

        foreach (var item in match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Mathew,
I tried this and it works as advertized except when the property value is null.

Answer (score 0):

And there is the old way ...

```
    public static IList<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> myList, string filter)
    {
        if (myList == null) return null;
        if (filter == null) return myList;

        var tfilter = filter.GetType();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.FullName == typeof(string).FullName);
        if (!properties.Any()) return null;


        var res = new List<T>();

        foreach(var el in myList)
        {
            foreach(var p in properties)
            {
                if ((string)p.GetValue(el) == filter)
                {
                    res.Add(el);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```